# my css codes does not work on some parts of my django project

Tags: python, html, css, django

So i am building a website with django but my css code working some parts while some parts dont.
this is my **home.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/static/css/home.css'%}">
    <script src="{% static 'fontawesomefree/js/all.min.js' %}"></script>
    <link href="{% static 'fontawesomefree/css/all.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    {% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            {% for product in product_list %}
            <div class="image">
                <img src="{{ product.image }}" alt="{{product.title}}">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="product-name">
                    <h3>{{product.title}}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="price-rating">
                    <h2>13.40$</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>

    {% endblock %}

</body>

</html>
```

and this is home.css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #dcdcdc;
}

.image {
    width: 10%;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 1200px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr))
}
```

I can change color of page but i cannot change the display or i cannot change sequence of items.
[image of my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OklLc.png)
so do you people have any idea to fix this issue? and my codes are not conflicting because i deleted all other components except navbar, thanks for your time.

could firefox be the reason of this issue? Because i've tried same codes in simple html/css and gave me the same solution.

Comment: Put all your css on base.html then extend base.html

Comment: But if i do that it will be very complex to conduct.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too sometimes. Try invalidate the caches of your browser, sometimes the css doesn't refresh when changing it.

Comment: So i already tried invalidate caches of browser but it did not gave me anything.

Answer (score 0):

on your page open devtool (usually ctrl+c) then navigate to network tab and check "disable cache" then refresh the page while the devtool is open  [image: devtool]

this usually happens because of [django caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/cache/) to make pages load faster...